# asp.mvc call javascript after partialview is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I realise I can solve the following problem by using AJAX. However, I didn't realise that a progress wheel would need to implemented so therefore I currently get results via an `ActionResult` method

```
   @Html.Action("devExpressGridView")
```

And at the server...

```
  return PartialView("devExpressGridView", Object);
```

So the problem is I need to call some javascript once the **partial view has been returned**

I know I can call some javascript on a button press or whatever to start to show the progress bar so this isn't no problem,

but once the results has been returned from the action method, I need to hide the progress wheel so the user knows the data retrieval has been done.

I basically need to fire ssomething like

```
// Once the action method has been completed, fire this...

        function hideProgress() {
                spinner.fadeOut("fast");
                spinnerVisible = false;
        };
```

is there a way to do this without AJAX?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can take a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a $(document).ready in the partial view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //do something here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My god, why do I always think the logic has to be surreal! Many thanks..so simple!